# jQuery JSon is not parsed

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse received JSON object but *obj* is always null and *obj.d* is undefined. Where is the problem?

JSon response

```
{"d":"psize=a4&porient=portrait&margintop=10&marginleft=5&marginright=5&marginbottom=10&title=&author=&subject=&keywords=&userpass=&ownerpass=&coverpage=http%3A%2F%2F&conversiondelay=1&allowscript=true"}
```

The code which call server and receive response above from server

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/LoadOptions",
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(obj.d);                    
                },
                error: ""
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `$.parseJSON` if your dataType is `json`.

`data` is the javascript object itself.

Comment: Not "json object"... JavaScript object :)